# Select unique value with most recent date, grouping by another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two joined tables, one lists devices IDs and names the other IDs and date of the most recent inventory collection. Using below query I will see something like that:

```
SELECT d.DeviceName, d.DeviceID, r.InvDate FROM Device d
JOIN Report r on d.DeviceID = r.DeviceID
```

- DeviceName   DeviceID    InvDate
- Computer1    101     22/4/2020
- Computer2    102     20/4/2020
- Computer3    103     19/4/2020
- Computer4    104     5/3/2020
- Computer4    105     22/4/2020
- Computer5    106     20/4/2020

as you can see some names can be duplicated.

How can I extract list of unique Names, (EDIT: together with their IDs) and the most recent inventory date?
In some perfect world I'd do below

```
SELECT d.DeviceID, MAX(r.InvDate) FROM Device d
JOIN Report r on d.DeviceID = r.DeviceID
GROUP BY d.DeviceName
```

Comment: If you want the Names, I'd consider select d.DeviceName etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by `row_number()` as well.

```
select
    DeviceName,
    DeviceID,
    InvDate
from
(
    select
        DeviceName,
        d.DeviceID,
        InvDate,
        row_number() over (partition by DeviceName order by InvDate desc) as rnk
    from device
    join report r
    on d.DeviceID = r.DeviceID
) vals
where rnk = 1
order by    
    DeviceID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `apply` for this:

```
SELECT d.DeviceID, d.DeviceName, r.*
FROM Device d OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) r.*
      FROM report r
      WHERE d.DeviceID = r.DeviceID
      ORDER BY r.InvDate DESC
     ) r;
```

Note only is this more efficient than using `ROW_NUMBER()` (in general), but it is a nice introduce to lateral joins.